# Explanation of a ternary conditional expression

Tags: expression, ternary-operator

The ternary conditional expression is shown below:

```
#define _trans(x,bit1,bit2) \ 
((bit1==bit2)?(x&bit1):(x&bit1)?bit2:0)
```

Can anyone help me explain this expression? Or how to split this expression into several parts.

Comment: It is straightforward to explain if you understand what the ternary operator `...? ... : ...` does. However, what does *Or how to split this expression into several parts.* mean? Do you want to get at intermediate values and put those values into variables?

Comment: @gbulmer But what does the second `:` mean in my expression? The colon at last. There are 2 colons in the expression...

Comment: If `bit1` is equal to `bit2`, then the result is `(x&bit1)`, if not, the result is `(x&bit1)?bit2:0`, am I right? @gbulmer

Comment: Yes @HuangJie, I've written out a more complete explanation for you if it helps.

Comment: There are two colons, and two question marks because there are two ternary operations. `(x&bit1)?bit2:0)` is a ternary operation, and it is only needed/evaluated when `(bit1==bit2)` is false. When `(bit1==bit2)` is true the result is `(x&bit1)` so `(x&bit1)?bit2:0)` is never evaluated.

Comment: Yes, you are exactly correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ternary operators can always be rewritten into if-else statements with the following method:

```
(EXPRESSION) ? (RESULT1) : (RESULT2)
```

This is equivalent to

```
if (EXPRESSION) { 
  return RESULT1; 
} else {
  return RESULT2;
}
```

So in your specific case

```
EXPRESSION = (bit1 == bit2)
RESULT1 = x&bit1
RESULT2 = x&bit1 ? bit2 : 0
```

Now we see that this was a chained ternary expression all along. Jeeze this is some gross code. RESULT2 is then

```
EXPRESSION2 = x&bit1
RESULT2,1 = bit2
RESULT2,2 = 0
```

So now we can write the (somewhat more readable) version:

```
if (bit1 == bit2) {
  return x&bit1;
} else {
  if (x&bit1) {
    return bit2;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks buddy. That's just what I'm thinking.